# Изменить имя пакета android

Tags: android, android-studio, package

Появилось необходимость переименовать имя пакета приложения в Android Studio.
Попытался переименовать с помощью [этой инструкции на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package).

Проблема в том, что первоначальное имя пакета состоит не из трех слов, а из двух.
А мне надо переименовать в трех-словное название пакета.

Comment: да вы можете вообще не менять. Поменяйте в гредле, потом в манифесте писать полные имена а не с точки да и всё.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Переименуйте две имеющиеся части пакета
2. Создайте в конечном основном (т.е. втором) пакете требуемый 3-ий.
3. Переместите всё что есть в этот третий пакет

Comment: А можно ли с помощью рефактора андроид студио переименовать во всех файлах содержащих имя пакета, в том числе хмл?

Comment: @Соколов, в теории, когда вы перетащите в студии пакеты старые в новый пакет вс так и произойдёт - всё везде переименуется правильно